# grunt-email-workflow Grunt tasks?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm using [Lee Munroe's grunt-email-workflow](https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-workflow) to build out a set of email templates but I am not able to find where are the tasks configured.

When I run "grunt" from the terminal I can see that few tasks are executed:
-clean
-sass
-assemble pages
-juice
etc.

[image]

But the Gruntfile.js does not contain anything a part from:

```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {

    // Pass data to tasks
    data: {

      // Re-usable filesystem path variables
      paths: {
        src:        'src',
        src_img:    'src/img',
        dist:       'dist',
        dist_img:   'dist/img',
        preview:    'preview'
      },

      // secrets.json is ignored in git because it contains sensitive data
      // See the README for configuration settings
      secrets: grunt.file.readJSON('secrets.json')

    }
  });
};
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[load-grunt-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-grunt-config) is auto-loading the required grunt modules located in the [package.json](https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-workflow/blob/master/package.json) of the project. This is where `clean` (grunt-contrib-clean) `sass` (grunt-sass) etc are coming from.

[This File](https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-workflow/blob/master/grunt/aliases.yaml) determines which tasks are run by grunt

Comment: I would wager that some of the installed packages are dependencies of the main tasks.

Comment: @MaRco85 - You can see here where `load-grunt-config` was added which shows that it does explain where these tasks are coming from: https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-workflow/pull/36/files.

Which ones are not being called?

This file registers the tasks also: https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-workflow/blob/master/grunt/aliases.yaml

Comment: Thanks @SlashmanX they are actually defined in aliases.yaml. It's the first time I see this kind of configuration